# OAuth machine to machine communication

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

Is it necessary to use an OAuth if the communication is exclusive for a machine to machine only? Right now, I am using IP restriction plus private key.

Answer (score 10):

It is nice to keep your authentication frameworks consistent across applications deployed in the same infrastructure.

Therefore, if you are already using OAuth 2.0 somewhere in your environment, taking advantage of the [client credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) can be advantageous for server-to-server calls to still be authenticated using the same framework but not requiring any user during the authorization flow.

The flow is quite simple:

1. Make a `POST` request from the client application to the authorization server

   ```
    POST https://api.oauth2server.com/token
        grant_type=client_credentials&
        client_id=CLIENT_ID&
        client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET
   ```
2. Receive the OAuth token response containing an access_token and refresh token

   ```
    {
      "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
      "token_type":"example",
      "expires_in":3600,
      "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
      "example_parameter":"example_value"
    }
   ```